# How to create exe file of javafx application

Tags: java, deployment, installation, javafx, javafx-2

I have created a desktop application using javafx. It uses the database of mysql. And by using Netbeans I  packaged the application into running jar.

Now I want to distribute the application  as a exe file for the windows users. Now my problem is how to create exe file from the jar and how that exe will connect with the database.

Comment: If that's what you want to do [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) will give you plenty of scenarios. However, depending on your requirement, a deployment via Java Web Start might be smoother and more appropriate.

Comment: If your question is about packaging, here is one option - http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/. How the exe connects to database is  not really question- it should work as it is from normal jar execution.

Comment: I got the point of assylias and looking at it.

Comment: Thanks Jayan for your comment but i have done the packaging and created the jar file but i want to convert it in exe

Comment: launch4j does exactly that.. Anyway the link from assylas points to a nice artcile @ http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: If you don't mind paying for it, you can look at exe4j. It supports x32 & x64 bit, imbedded jar or external jar support. I've been using it for a nnber of years and find it very suitable

Comment: But my question has one more thing that how it will connect with the database i am using mysql

Comment: Is the database to be installed locally on the client machine, or is it remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exe4j or install4j may be a good option

Answer (score 5):

There is an official [Java Packager Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html) which is part of the JavaFX suite. It can create [self-contained applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) including a native launcher: `.exe` on Windows, `.app` bundle on OS X, etc. By default it bundles a JRE as part of the application, but [this behavior can be changed to use the system JRE instead](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#2) if desired.

You can call the Java packager via Ant tasks, the `javapackager` command line tool, or using the NetBeans IDE. See the [Java deployment guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I work for Excelsior.

We've just discovered that [Excelsior JET seems to already support JavaFX 2](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/blog/excelsior-jet/javafx-2-already-supported/). You can compile your JavaFX app down to native code with it, as opposed to `(launch|exe|install)4j` that are only capable of creating EXE launchers and wrappers.

That said, a launcher/wrapper generator may be a better fit for your needs and budget.