# Spring boot application to exe with Java and mysql

Tags: java, spring-boot, package, exe

I have a spring boot application as jar packaged. I want to run this application in a computer which has no jre even. Is there any mechanism where I can bundle jre and mysql with project and convert it as an exe/msi, which can be installed and ran from any computer.

Comment: You have to have a JRE.

Comment: @duffymo, Yes, but my question is, is it possible to add jre and mysql with my project and make it as app.exe, while I install app.exe in any computer, jre and mysql will be available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create exe file of javafx application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699883/how-to-create-exe-file-of-javafx-application). The javapackager also works on non javafx applications.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to bundle the jar with your code but i don't think that you can bundle the mysql along with you can just wrap the queries along with that even when you wrap the jar with your code it not possible to run without installing the java version in your system which needs to be the same version as the jre version that you have been wrapped along with the code.
If you using the spring then you wanna wrap all the dependency file along with the jre to wrap and then to configure the build path with the jdk.